# xml parsing utf-8 characters in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

I have an xml file with node

```
<formatted_address>
  Selimiye Mh., Vehbi Koç Acil Tıp Mrk., 34660 Üsküdar/İstanbul, Turkey
</formatted_address>
```

My oracle code is looks like this

```
  select xmlsequence(v_xml_resp.extract('/result')) into nodelist from dual;
Extracting "address" node
     node.extract('//address/text()').getstringval();
```

The extracted node value looks like this
    Selimiye Mh., Vehbi KoÃ§ Acil TÄ±p Mrk., 34660 ÃskÃ¼dar/Ä°stanbul, Turkey

Any idea how to fix this

Thanks

Comment: Does your database character set support UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, it supports UTF8

Comment: How did you insert the data into database? Most probably you NLS_LANG is set wrong and you inserted wrong data.

Comment: I tried to print this     dbms_output.put_line(node.extract('//formatted_address/text()').getstringval());

Comment: Yes, v_xml_resp := xmltype(v_resp_txt); I tried  this also  v_xml_resp :=  XMLType(convert(v_resp_txt, 'UTF8'));

Answer (score 0):

Most probalby you get `Selimiye Mh., Vehbi KoÃ§ Acil TÄ±p Mrk., 34660 ÃskÃ¼dar/Ä°stanbul, Turkey` because that is the content which actually **is** in your database.

I guess data where written to database with wrong encoding of you client.

Use following test to understand the issue:

First create a table in your DB:

```
CREATE MY_TABLE (t VARCHAR2(100), ts TIMESTAMP);
```

Then create a SQL-File like this:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('Selimiye Mh., Vehbi Koç Acil Tıp Mrk., 34660 Üsküdar/İstanbul, Turkey', SYSTIMESTAMP);
COMMIT;
EXIT;
```

Save the file as `my_insert.sql`, for example. Ensure that character encoding is set to `UTF-8`. In most modern editors you can set this in the save options. Note, a SQL-File must not have a **BOM** (Byte Order Mark)

Then run following commands from command line (for Windows):

```
set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8
sqlplus <your_user>/<password>@<your_DB> @my_insert.sql

set NLS_LANG=.WE8MSWIN1252
sqlplus <your_user>/<password>@<your_DB> @my_insert.sql
```

Check content of table `MY_TABLE`. You will see, the first entry is `Selimiye Mh., Vehbi Koç Acil Tıp Mrk., 34660 Üsküdar/İstanbul, Turkey`, whereas the second is `Selimiye Mh., Vehbi KoÃ§ Acil TÄ±p Mrk., 34660 ÃskÃ¼dar/Ä°stanbul, Turkey`

Most likely your data where inserted from an UTF-8 file but client `NLS_LANG` was not set properly.

Solution could be tricky: Perhaps it works when you copy/paste the XML into a new text file, save this as UTF-8 and insert the data again (with proper `NLS_LANG`)